# Determining how many Bytes is in a CSV row in Golang

Tags: csv, go, byte

I have a `test.csv` that I would line to read line by line and determine how many bytes are in each row.

This should be 37 bytes below as I am on Windows and first two rows have `\r\n` adding 4 total bytes.

```
foo,bar,baz
100,200,300
400,500,600
```

I want to simply determine how many bytes are in each row using a `csv.NewReader()`. However, I know that csv.Reader is not counting the commas and the `\n` in each row when byte counting in my below code.

Should I add some math for the number of commas in each row + number of rows add 2 bytes for `\r\n` -1 one byte for the final row since it does not have a \r\n? This feels a bit hacky so I'd rather see if there is a better solution to my byte counting problem.

my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("test.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("file total bytes is %d\n", fileInfo.Size())

    // init reader
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)

    // extract the header
    headers, err := reader.Read()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("headers are: %+v\n", headers)

    byteCounter := 0
    for {
        // if we reached end of file, stop
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        // read a record
        record, err := reader.Read()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        // loop through each record and count how many bytes
        for _, item := range record {
            byteCounter += len(item)
            fmt.Printf("record is %d bytes\n", len(item))
        }
        fmt.Println("total bytes so far is: ", byteCounter)

    }
}
```

Comment: Also, be aware that the CSV Reader will drop the carriage return from \r\n sequences. The [CSV docs](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv) mention this in the 4th paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Reader.InputOffset](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Reader.InputOffset) to get the current position in the file:

```
fmt.Println("total bytes so far is: ", reader.InputOffset())
```

https://go.dev/play/p/cgqq9woK02w

To get the bytes per line, subtract from the previous offset.

```
prevOffset := reader.InputOffset()

for {
    ...
    // read a record
    _, err := reader.Read()
    ...
    fmt.Println("line length is: ", reader.InputOffset()-prevOffset)
    prevOffset = reader.InputOffset()

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/cXCfogUBcdy